# KendoUI Datasoure Fetch function to append to Array

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have some code that I am trying to evolve into something more complex however for some reason I cannot get it to even append to my current array. If I use console.log then it will output the desired data. Here is the code...

```
var p = [];
DataSource.fetch(function () {
    var item = CREAInfo.SiteSelector.DataSource.at(0);
    p.push(item.Phase); 
});
```

For whatever reason the array 'p' still comes up empty...

Comment: Are you loading the data synchronously or asynchronously?  If it is async, then you might be trying to read `p` before it is populated.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly hitting some sort of race condition.  Without a broader context of how the code snippet you posted is being executed, it is impossible to be more specific.  To prove the hypothesis, try doing a console.log on the item you are about the push onto the array, then after you have pushed it onto the array, do a console.log of `p.length`.

Assuming that the item is indeed being pushed on properly, there are two possibilities which would explain the behavior.

1)  The code which inspects the array is executing before the callback which populates the array has executed.

2)  Another piece of code is emptying the array after the callback has executed, but before it has been inspected.